# What is audio focus in Android class AudioManager?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

The `AudioManager` class has a method `abandonAudioFocus()` and another method `requestAudioFocus()`. I wonder what is audio focus? And what happens if an `AudioManager` object gets the audio focus or lost the audio focus?

Thank you!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It has to do with priority when using the speakers, to prevent playing many things at once or being overridden. If you `requestAudioFocus()`, you're declaring that you want control. You can then listen with `onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange)` to see if anything else tries to play a sound. You may forcefully lose focus (like during a phone call) but then you can gain it later. You should `abandonAudioFocus()` when you're finished.

Comment: What should I do if I want my audio to keep playing, without having anything (not even phone call) to play with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
  AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                        AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener =
                                focusChange -> {
                    };
                        int result = am.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,
                                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);
                        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                            mp = new android.media.MediaPlayer();
                            mp.setOnCompletionListener(mediaPlayer -> {
                                am.abandonAudioFocus(focusChangeListener);
                            });
                            mp.setDataSource("/data/data/" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/rasa.wav");
                            mp.prepare();
                            mp.start();
                        }
```